# DataGridView Cell and Edit hangs Up

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to take input from user via textbox and on button click based on the data inserted find some more data from database and then putting all in a datagrid view but my application hangs up when i click the button. Plz Help!

```
private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if(e.ColumnIndex==0)
        {
            string newvalue;
            newvalue = Search_Product.Text.ToString();
            con.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Product_Code,Rate,SalePrice,CGST,SGST FROM Product_Master where Product_Name='"+newvalue+"'",con);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            da.Fill(dt);
            float CGST = (float.Parse(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()) * float.Parse(dt.Rows[0][3].ToString())) / 100;
            float SGST = (float.Parse(dt.Rows[0][1].ToString()) * float.Parse(dt.Rows[0][4].ToString())) / 100;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[1].Value = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[3].Value = dt.Rows[0][2].ToString();
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[4].Value = CGST;
            dataGridView1.Rows[e.RowIndex].Cells[5].Value = SGST;
            con.Close();
        }
        //column multiplication
        foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
        {
            row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[6].Index].Value = (Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[2].Index].Value) * Convert.ToDouble(row.Cells[dataGridView1.Columns[3].Index].Value));
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridViewCellEventArgs ke = e as DataGridViewCellEventArgs;
        dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(sender, ke);
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint into da.fill and see if its hangs there?

Comment: Sorry! Didnt get you

Comment: I have figured it out to be some problem with rowindex, by replacing it with a numerical value it works fine